# Android Notification

Tags: android

How to pass value of notification's when one row is clicked ,to another activity for displaying details in android?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

`Notification n = new Notification(icon, text, when);

String contentTitle = "I am expanded title";

String contentText = "I am expanded text";

Intent intent = new Intent(this, TargetActivity.class);

// Put additional stuff into the created intent

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, 1);

n.setLatestEventInfo(this, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);`

Put your information in the intent, using Intent.putExtra methods, and retrieve them in the target activity.